# where to get jar which has libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream

Tags: jar

I am searching for almost 3 hours and I am unable to find the jar which has libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream If anyone know please guide me on this. thanks

I downloaded jars from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/httpresponsecache.htm but couldn't find...

Please look at this screenshot, I am adding the correct jar but still I can't import it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking at wrong package name, the fully qualified class name as per our discussion in chat and your image snapshot is as below.

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream
```

and not

```
libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream
```

You can download the file for the class mentioned above which is part of [HTTP Commons from this location](http://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.3.6-bin.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks for responding.. I tried with com.integralblue.httpresponsecache.compat.libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream but it doesn't work..

Comment: It does show, but it doesn't let us create the object using that Class name

Comment: I have put the link of zip file which contains the jar in it. In that jar the class file is there.

Comment: @makki now you are changing your question. Can you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am not changing my question :) the thing is `import com.integralblue.httpresponsecache.compat.libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream;` doesn't work with the jar you shared

Comment: Please share the whole problem statement you are trying to achieve and what problem you are facing while doing that. For example while using the class (discussed above) in your custom class you are getting any exception than share that exception details etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66745/discussion-between-makki-and-shaikh-mohammed-shariq).